# int values in dict appending as list

Tags: python

I have a for loop which is going through multiple dictionaries and adding the values under common keys. The input dictionary has keys that are strings and values that are int's. For some reason its adding the values as lists of one value `(e.g. {"01":[12],[44]})`. I want it to add the int on its own but cant get that working for some reason. I'm using the code below, is there something i am missing ?

```
    dw = defaultdict()
    dw = {}

    for key, value in listb.items():
        dw[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Why do you make `dw` a `defaultdict` and then make it a regular dict on the very next line? If you take out the second line and change the first to make a `defaultdict(list)`, it should work.

Comment: that was a mistake

Comment: Does that run? Looks like you would get `KeyError` to me.

Comment: yeah does give key error

Comment: Please clarify: If `dicta = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` and `dictb = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}` and you join the two, do you want `{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [5]}` or `{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': 5}`? This is not clear from your question.

Comment: I want it to output {"a": [1,3], "b":[2,4] , "c":5 }

Comment: Why would you want this? Anyway, you can always just loop through your dict and for any list of length one, replace it with the single value...

Comment: @dmnte, please show us what the dictionaries are like in `listb` so your question will get more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forgo all good practice and not use `defaultdict(list)`, you can use `setdefault` and call it every single time you choose to add a value. This is inefficient and not idiomatic, but it will work.

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: a = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: b = {}

In [4]: a[1].append(1)

In [5]: b.setdefault(1, []).append(1)

In [6]: a
Out[6]: defaultdict(list, {1: [1]})

In [7]: b
Out[7]: {1: [1]}

In [8]:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add key/value pairs to the dictionary (and not append to an array), it's:

```
for key, value in listb.items():
  dw[key] = value
```

EDIT: or is it something like this you're after?

```
   listb = {'1': 3, '2': 5}
   dw = {'1': 5, '2': 9}

   for key, value in listb.items():
      if key not in dw.keys():
          dw[key] = []
      else:
          dw[key] = [dw[key]]
      dw[key].append(value)
```

which gives `dw = {'2': [9, 5], '1': [5, 3]}`

Comment: i want to append it, i dont want it to append as a single value list

Comment: @dmnte can you give an example of an item in `listb`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the values in the dicts are ints (not lists):

```
dw = {}
for key, value in listb.items():
    try: # Key exists in dictionary and value is a list
        dw[key].append(value)
    except KeyError: # Key does not yet exist in dictionary
        dw[key] = value
    except AttributeError: # Key exist in dictionary and value is not a list 
        dw[key] = [dw[key], value]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `list` like `listb = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'b': 1}]`, you can try this:

```
dw = {}

for d in listb:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in dw:
            if isinstance(dw[k], list):
                dw[k].append(v)
            elif isinstance(dw[k], int):                
                dw[k] = [dw[k], v]
        else:
            dw[k] = v

print(dw)

{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4, 1], 'c': 5}
>>>
```